# DeprecationWarning: 'session_cookie_name' is deprecated and will be removed in Flask 2.3. Use 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME' in 'app.config' instead

Tags: python, flask, web, session, web-development-server

I get this error when I click a button of a form to many times or just randomly sometimes or when a webhook is called. I don't understand what's wrong. I think the problem might be here:

```
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_NAME"] = "session"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
Session(app)`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well I get the error stated in the question randomly and my app breaks(500 Internal server error). In this particular application I am using login session. Since the error mentioned app.config i thought that it has something to do with the code above. I have also have another app (app2) who uses stripe webhook and whenever the webhook is called I get this error. However I must clarify that in the app2 I get this error only in production, I have deployed the app and it has no problems. So I don't really know why this happens or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is from Flask-Session. There is an issue for it on Github: https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session/issues/150 but there doesn't seem to be much activity anymore in the repository.

I fixed it in my project by using [Flask-Session2](https://pypi.org/project/flask-session2/), which is an actively maintained fork of Flask-Session.

**Edit**: It's fixed now, upgrade to Flask-Session 0.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am really newby to programming, so my answer will seem pretty dumb, but I just happened to be in the same situation with this error for some routes in my flask app. I tried deleting cookies and cache from my browser and seems it worked! Hope this helps.